# Lex v1 chatbot integration with connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I have a lex v1 chatbot which has a SpeakToAgent intent. I want to be able to connect with a customer agent using amazon Connect whenever a user uses this intent. All my other intents work as expected for this chatbot.

I have created users, a queue, routing profile and a flow in my connect instance. I have also added my classic v1 bot in the connect instance and specified it in the get-customer-input block in my flow. Upon logging in as a customer support agent in aws connect and triggering the SpeakToAgent intent on my chatbot, I don't see any notifications pop up. I do not see any errors either and nothing shows up in the Connect Cloudwatch logs so I am guessing the connection from my Lex bot to Connect is not working.

I would really appreciate any help to get this thing working. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Could anyone help me out on this? Still stuck